# ADB2C "resource does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present"

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

While attempting to delete a user from Azure ADB2C, the following error appears now and again, not consistently.

> "Resource 'User_*GUID*' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property
> objects are not present."

Calling a Delete on "https://graph.windows.net/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/users/GUID?api-version=1.6"

Am using the Graph API for .Net as per https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet

Any ideas on what causes this error or what to look for?

Comment: Have you checked the deleted user in your portal? And strongly recommend you try it by using [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Comment: User is not deleted, am trying to delete a user but get the error as described and user does not get deleted. Cannot use Graph Explorer as is not approved with our organisation. Still wondering what the error actually means and what causes it?

Comment: Did you log in the Graph API as the global admin or just as the user? If you use the Graph API cannot delete, have you tried to delete the user in the portal?

Comment: I tried on my side if as the global admin, the user could be deleted. And if as the user, it prompts `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`

Comment: @SunnySun-MSFT the intent is to have a web app delete a user in ADB2C using the Graph API. This is coded in the web app, sometimes it works and user is deleted, sometimes it fails with the error in my post. Trying to understand why the API is inconsistent in the result of the Delete action.

Comment: When using Azure ad graph API, I also got this kind error for sometimes, and everything is ok, it still returned errors.

Comment: Also share that experience.The problem case is getting the error and the user has not been deleted. This happens even if we query B2C to confirm the user exists first. Trying to understand why? What does the error actually mean and what can we do to avoid getting it and have the user successfully deleted as per the request being sent to B2C.

Comment: For your issue, you could request support from the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com). For the details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Comment: Have done, replicated the issue last week with an engineer and awaiting a response. Will update this when the SR reaches a conclusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our particular case the error reflects the replication process operating within B2C. The delete on a B2C user can be called very quickly < 1 second after the user is created in B2C.

B2C replicates its data throughout MS datacentres and the delete call is not guaranteed to hit a datacentre to which the user has been replicated as of yet. Hence the error that the resource does not exist.

Replication can take upwards of 90 seconds to be complete to all datacentres so need to adopt a wait and retry strategy to ensure deletion is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the Microsoft Graph API is strongly recommended for you, for the details, you could refer to [active-directory-graph-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart) and [microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).

For your issue, you could check the deleted user by using [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#), and it required the global admin:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

And for this operation required permissions:
[image]
The response should like this:
[image]
For the details, you could refer to [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get).

If your response like this, you could follow the next step to delete the user as a global admin:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}
```

And the required permissions:
[image]

The response like this:
[image]

For the details, you could refer to [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_delete).